# How to Get ngrok https URL with pyngrok in Python

Tags: python, pyngrok

How would I write a Python program that automates `ngrok` connections? I've tried using `pyngrok`, but I want to display an `https` URL and it always returns `http`.

Comment: There are multiple questions here in the same question. Try dividing up these into seperate questions so that people know which one to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per the `pyngrok` docs](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#open-a-tunnel), two tunnels are opened by default, one `http`, one `https`. Just use `bind_tls=True` if you only want the `https` tunnel and it will be returned.

```
from pyngrok import ngrok

https_tunnel = ngrok.connect(bind_tls=True)
```

If you want to know *how* `pyngrok` does this, [its code is open source](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using pyngrok version 4.1, passing the argument `bind_tls= True` directly will raise an error. Try using:

```
options = {
   "bind_tls": True
}


public_url = ngrok.connect(port='80',options=options)
```

That will work.