# static url in pyngrok or ngrok in google colab

Tags: flask, ngrok, pyngrok

hey i am trying to run this code in google colab or other virtual machine and i need to make sure only static server instead of random url everytime generated is used for this one what should i do ?

```
**
!pip install flask pyngrok flask-ngrok
!ngrok authtoken {{my-auth-token}}
from flask import Flask
from pyngrok import ngrok
import os

app = Flask(name)

@app.route("/")
def home():
return "Hello from Flask"
public_url = ngrok.connect(5000, bind_tls=True)
print("Tracking URL:", public_url)

app.run() 
**
```

everytime i run i am not able to get a new server url but i need a static server provided by ngrok.

Thanks in advance

alteast somework around of what can i add to get  a static url  in free version as they have mentioned but i am not able to do so in google colab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get ngrok https URL with pyngrok in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66615463/how-to-get-ngrok-https-url-with-pyngrok-in-python). The linked docs also have Flask examples and Google Colab examples, but I think the main problem is you're mixing two unrelated libraries, `flask-ngrok` and `pyngrok`. You only need `pyngrok`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this package (https://pypi.org/project/ngrok-flask-cart/). I built it for a separate project (https://github.com/nathanReitinger/CART/tree/main), but I think the ngrok-flask part applies here.

```
pip install ngrok-flask-cart
...
from ngrok_flask_cart import run_with_ngrok
...
run_with_ngrok(app=app, domain='--domain=<YOUR_STATIC_DOMAIN>', auth_token='<YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN>')
```